# clojurescript reader/read-string returns null

Tags: clojurescript

I upgraded the clojurescript version of a working application to 0.0-2030 and suddenly reader/read-string returns null, e.g:

```
(js/alert (str "reader returned ["  (reader/read-string "{1 2}") "]"))
```

shows []. I compile with the cljsbuild plugin:

```
 :cljsbuild {:builds [{:source-paths ["src/cljs/main"],
                    :compiler {:pretty-print true,
                               :output-to "resources/public/cljs/main.js",
                               :optimizations :whitespace}}
```

reeader is defined like this:

```
(:require           
    [cljs.reader :as reader]
```

What can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I've tried to setup a single clojurescript project following the minimal instructions detailed here: http://swannodette.github.io/2013/10/27/the-essence-of-clojurescript/

This project also uses the same clojurescript version

```
:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.5.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2030"]]
```

And this is the code I used into:

```
(ns hello-world.core
    (:require [cljs.reader :as reader]))

(js/alert (str "reader returned ["  (reader/read-string "{1 2}") "]"))
```

And works fine!

Comment: Sure. I work on this project for months and this part always worked fine. Until today, when I upgraded. So I wonder what can have gone wrong. I am not going to setup a new project, I have the fix the one I already have.

Comment: @Assen, have you tried doing lein cljsbuild clean? You may have old compiled files laying around.

Comment: @jbm, thanks, thanks a lot, as embarrassed I am that I didn't try this before posting.  Issue solved.

Comment: my response is related to demonstrate that the clojurescript version and reader function works, then you have to try lein clean and lein cljs build clean as @Assen says and I was going to propose